# Implementing AdMob Rewarded video ads in IOS module( libGDX)

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, mobivm

I've added interstitial admob ads in my ios version of my libgdx game.
but i can't find something like GADRewardedVideo

```
// Build.Gradle
implementation "org.robovm:robopods-google-mobile-ads-ios:1.6.0"

// IOSLauncher
import org.robovm.pods.google.mobileads.GADInterstitial;
import org.robovm.pods.google.mobileads.GADRequest;
```

I imported this from robopods, is there something missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version `1.6.0` of `robopods-google-mobile-ads-ios` artifact under `org.robovm` group is too old(~Aug, 2015).

[RoboVM is no more](https://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3925), try [MobiVM](http://robovm.mobidevelop.com) (fork based on the last open-source version of RoboVM)

Inject artifact under mobivm hood :

```
implementation "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robopods-google-mobile-ads-ios:2.2.2"
```

If you like to work with snapshot version, use `2.2.3-SNAPSHOT`

---

Hopefully you've added `GoogleMobileAds.framework` in your ios module before Gradle injection.

Comment: thanks for your answer! can you tell me more about `GoogleMobileAds.framework` ?

Comment: you've to add http://dl.google.com/googleadmobadssdk/googlemobileadssdkios.zip data in your ios module